# Redux is able to set characters to an array however the remove action does not seem to reach the reducer

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I am using redux to update an array of characters as a user types or erases it, so that when the user correctly types the entire phrase I can set a success flag.

So far when typing in characters the redux type SET_INPUT fires off and updates my state but unfortunately my REMOVE_INPUT doesn't seem to fire off but it does however reach the action.

My Reducer:
import { GET_PHRASE, SET_LOADING, SET_INPUT, REMOVE_INPUT } from "../types";

```
const initialState = {
    level: 1,
    phrase: null,
    scrambledPhrase: null,
    words: [],
    input: [],
    goal: [],
    success: false,
    loading: false,
};

export const phraseReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_PHRASE:
            return {
                ...state,
                phrase: action.payload.sentence,
                scrambledPhrase: action.payload.scrambledPhrase,
                words: action.payload.phrase.split(" "),
                goal: action.payload.phrase.split(""),
                loading: false,
            };
        case SET_INPUT:
            console.log("setting input");
            return {
                ...state,
                input: [...state.input, action.payload],
            };
        case REMOVE_INPUT:
            console.log("removing input");
            return {
                ...state,
                input: [...state.input.slice(0, -1)],
            };
        case SET_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

My Actions:

```
import { GET_PHRASE, SET_LOADING, SET_INPUT, REMOVE_INPUT } from "../types";
import axios from "axios";

export const getPhrase = (level) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        setLoading();

        await axios
            .get(`MY ROUTE`)
            .then((res) => {
                // console.log(res);
                const sentence = res.data.data.phrase;
                const scrambledSentence = scramblePhrase(
                    res.data.data.phrase
                );

                dispatch({
                    type: GET_PHRASE,
                    payload: {
                        phrase: phrase.toLowerCase(),
                        scrambledPhrase: scrambledPhrase.toLowerCase(),
                    },
                });
            });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

// SET INPUT
export const setInput = (input) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_INPUT,
            payload: input,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

// REMOVE INPUT
export const removeInput = () => {
    try {
        console.log("remove reached in actions");
        return {
            type: REMOVE_INPUT,
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

// SET LOADING
export const setLoading = () => {
    console.log("Loading...");
    return {
        type: SET_LOADING,
    };
};
```

My Component to input a character:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// redux imports
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { setInput, removeInput } from "../redux/actions/phraseActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Character = ({ character, hasSpace, setInput }) => {
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState();

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        if (e.target.value === character) {
            // console.log("Success");
            setSuccess(true);
        } else {
            setSuccess(false);
        }
    };

    const keyedDown = (e) => {
        // check for space or a letter
        if (e.keyCode === 32 || (e.keyCode > 64 && e.keyCode < 91)) {
            setInput(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase());
        }
        // check for backspace
        else if (e.keyCode === 8) {
            removeInput();
        }
    };
    return (
        <div
            className={`character ${
                success ? "success" : hasSpace ? "space" : ""
            }`}
        >
            <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                required
                maxLength="1"
                size="1"
                onChange={handleChange}
                onKeyDown={keyedDown}
                className="input"
                autoComplete="off"
            ></input>
        </div>
    );
};

Character.propTypes = {
    setInput: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    removeInput: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    // define state
    phrase: state.phrase,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setInput, removeInput })(Character);
```

In my console you can see which points I am reaching:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler you are not calling `removeInput` that was provided by connect (props.removeInput) but the imported removeInput that doesn't dispatch anything and just returns an action object, so I suggest changing the component definition to:

```
const Character = ({ character, hasSpace, setInput, removeInput }) => {
```

In your reducer you can do: `input: state.input.slice(0, -1),` because [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) already returns a shallow copy of the array so no need to copy it with `[...]`

Comment: Ah jeez, I'm blind! Thank you!